# How to get org-mode to resume list numbering from where it left off

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21475047/52310

I want to write something like:

```
1. foo
2. bar

intervening text

3. baz
4. quux
```

The two easy almost-solutions are:

1. Make "intervening text" part of the first list:

   ```
   1. foo
   2. bar

       intervening text

   3. baz
   4. quux
   ```
2. Explicitly set the second list's number:

   ```
   1. foo
   2. bar

   intervening text

   3. [@3] baz
   4. quux
   ```

I'm exporting to LaTeX, but I'd prefer to avoid using anything LaTeX-specific.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
    1. foo
    2. bar <<list-end>>

    intervening text

    3. [@[[list-end]]] baz
    4. quux
```

Comment: The two "almost-easy" solutions [seem to be the best available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984604/have-org-mode-continue-a-numbered-list-rather-than-restarting). The problem is that as far as Orgmode is concerned, those are two different lists that have nothing to do with each other, and there isn't (as far as I know) a way to  automatically have one list continue where another ends.